# how to populate only first element from subdocument array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the myDocument schema:

```
{
  name: {type: String},
  data:  [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'myData'}],
}
```

my goal is to populate only first element from the data array.

```
myDocument.find({}).populate('data').exec();
```

I want selecet only first element from myData array (myDocument.data[0]).

*Should myDocument.data.length === 1 or 0 if array is emty*.

Answer (score 7):

I found populate `options` param which allows set `limit` for the populated array.

```
myDocument.find({}).populate({path: 'data', options: {limit: 1} }).exec();
```